# Custom Labels In Force.com Site

Tags: force.com-sites, customlabel, translation

I have enabled Translations, with languages English and Russian. I have made one Custom Label and added a Russian translation. I have added that Custom Label to my Force.com Site. What do I need to change in Salesforce to view the Russian translation of that Custom Label in my Force.com Site?

I have tried changing the `Locale` and `Language` of `Force.com Site Site Guest User` but it did not work.

Changing my language to Russian and viewing the VisualForce page as `/apex/PageName` did work - it translated the label into Russian, but that is not what I want. I.e., This is viewing the Visualforce page as ADMIN; I want to know how to achieve the same (view the Russian translation) when viewing the Force.com Site as an unauthenticated user.

Comment: I don't really understand what do you want. If you can see the translation on the page - what else?

Comment: @mast0r, I can see the translation when I view the Visualforce page as an Admin. I want to know how to achieve the same when viewing the Force.com Site as an unauthenticated user.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<apex:page sidebar="true" showHeader="false" language="ru">
```

The `language` parameter of the page decides language.

Make a getter setter variable in the controller and use `userinfo` to get the language or through the query and populate on the language parameter.

> http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_page.htm

This method works but still need to investigate more on why for unauthenticated user it's weird! Please try in different browser where only unauthenticated user is accessing page.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the custom labels you have translated are in vf tags  `<apex:outputText />` and not just stand alone text like `<p>{!$Label.MyLabel}</p>`