# Multi language using visualforce

Tags: visualforce, customlabel, language

Multi language using visualforce, i had to display multiple languages using custom labels how can i achieve it?? just by clicking on "french" link text in vf page must turn into french

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you need.  It sounds like you want a Visualforce that works in multiple languages.  How many languages? Which ones?  Will the list change over time or is it static?

Comment: please check this below question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5269/custom-labels-in-force-com-site

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the Translation Workbench, which is the SFDC feature which allows you to build multi-lingual SFDC instances.

Please review the documentation here which shows you how to use the Translation Workbench: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_wbench.htm&language=en and then refine your question.