# Working with Custom Labels to Support Different Languages

Tags: visualforce

Our app should support both Turkish and English.

I am using Custom Labels to define Turkish labels although I can not understand how can I define the English labels (in the same place) so that the visual force pages will dynamically use the proper labels (based on the user language) without me adding IF/ELSE code to use VF pages to use the right labels based on the user language.

Appreciate your help

Comment: Somewhat similar question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5269/custom-labels-in-force-com-site

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to activate the Translation Workbench (Setup --> Translation Workbench --> Translation Settings then Activate button). Then, add the language you want to enable.

When it's done, you have a related list on each custom label where you can add translation for each activated language.

Custom label value will be displayed according to the navigation language of the user.

Comment: I am using Turkish which is only available on the Platform level, in such case Translation Workbench is less relevant, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't know about Turkish but activate Translation Workbench is the only way to make translation related list available in the Custom Label menu

Comment: This is the correct way of doing it. We do this for 9 languages.